# Effect of downsizing on perceived sharpness

Tags: image-processing, resolution

Suppose an $N\times M$ image of an object is downsized to a $N'\times M'$ image using a standard algorithm such as bilinear.

How does that downsized image compare in sharpness to an image of the same object that was acquired at $N'\times M'$? In other words, if the goal is to end up with an $N'\times M'$ image of the object, is there any sharpness/resolution advantage to acquiring a higher resolution image of the object and downsizing it?

Assume a noiseless sensor, distortionless imaging and the same perspective in both images.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No. I'm after a conceptual understanding of the effect of downsizing a larger image and made up this example to stimulate discussion.

Comment: Thanks. There are many ways in which the images will be different: noise, perspective, distortion and sharpness for instance. You may want to narrow down the question to attract better answers.

Comment: "Stimulating discussion" isn't a StackExchange thing -- we're looking for questions that have definitive answers.  If you want a discussion then (sorry!) you need to take your question to another forum.  I suggest that you _edit your question_, heading it up with the statement that what you _really_ want is to understand the effect of downsizing a larger image.  It may be a good idea to put in disclaimers about the lens and imager involved -- I'd suggesting limiting the lenses to ones that follow a pinhole model, and the imager to a focal plane array without cos^4 or other FOV-ish effects.

Comment: I specifically stated that the two images were taken at the same distance from the subject so they will not differ in perspective. But since there seems to be such objection to my question I will try to reword it.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to have an image of 4000x2000 pixels, there are some potential advantages to using e.g. a 8000x4000 sensor camera, then downscaling.

1. Sensel spatial integration might be approximated as a «<100% fill-rate rect function». I.e. to some degree the sampling of the continuous image is far from a Nyquistian sampler.
2. Sensor micro lenses modify the sensel spatial integration, typically making it closer to 100% fill rate at the cost of some limitations in optical lens design.
3. To correct for sensel aliasing, some cameras employ an optical lowpass filter prior to sampling. This is basically a comb filter. Still far from a Nyquistian sampler.
4. In order to have color images, most cameras employ a color filter array (Bayer) that use 1/4 sensels each for red and blue, and 1/2 the sensels for green. Removing the individual channels from a Nyquistian sampler.

By oversampling in the camera, then downsampling using something like a windowed sinc resampler, you can have more control with the trade-off between passband flatness and stopband rejection. Meaning that you can optimize for «sharp» image, at the cost of more visible aliasing if you like.

Provided that bumping resolution does not incur other quality issues in the camera, operational disadvantages or lack of bandwidth/storage.

I believe that some cameras have a spatial response that is very «dirac-y». I.e. little prefiltering, and sensels will tend to be different from neighbours, producing high acutance across edges. Some photographers like that.